# How to Debug Python built-in module efficiently?

Tags: python, standard-library

recently I'm learning Python standard library and reading the source code

help for understanding I copy code segment and paste to python interpreter

but I feel it's inefficient and unwise ('cause import module won't got the `_`)

I wanna to find a efficient way to test a module, include the _var and _func()

thanks for any good idea  -- a green man

Answer (score 0):

The module `pdb` is an interactive source code debugger for Python programs.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace() #  insert this line at the location you want to break
```

Documentation is provided here : [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)